# Synchronize vim undo history for files on dropbox across computers

Tags: vim

Is there some way I can synchronize the undo history for files I have on Dropbox and which I edit on multiple computers? I guess the simplest way would be to store them on Dropbox as well?

I know about `undofile`, but would like to use a specific undodir for only a restricted subset of files (those on dropbox). The following would do this for all files on each machine, which I would like to avoid.

```
set undofile
set undodir=/home/username/Dropbox/.vimundo/
```

Comment: so if I understood you right, you want to edit some files on your Dropbox, and those file you want to keep the undo files also on Dropbox, so that you can fetch the undo-his when load the file on any computer. Then why not just in all your vimrcs, setting `set udf` and remove the undodir setting. (using its default `.`)?

Comment: plus, in your situation, the default undodir `.` is most reliable option IMO. Because, if you set another DIR, the undofile will be named as the full path of the file. So in case you have a different username on some machines, you will have problem to load the undofiles when you read the buffers/files.

Comment: Usernames are not an issue. I have an undodir and backupdir set in my vimrc to avoid clutter. I agree, if there is no easy solution I will just delete the undodir setting on both machines.

Answer (score 0):

The `'undodir'` option is a **global** one. So, unless you dynamically switch it with `:autocmd`, for your purpose of sharing the undo information across machines, it best to keep it at its default setting:

```
:set undodir=.
```